# How can I insert attendance(may be true or false just) in sqlite database for each and every day

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making an attendance management system. I want to user sqlite database for android . everything is good but how can I insert attendance in database for each and every new date . Example : today is 16th july I am taking todays attendance but tomorrow also I need attendance for tomorrow data and so on through the month and years .

Comment: Upload the code you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can create user table with `UserID` , `Name` and ect columns
and attendance table with `Date`,`FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES UserTable(UserID)`  ,`Attendance` (INTEGER)( 1->true and 0->false) ,`EntranceTime` and ect

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below table structure.

**Columns:**

- **id** : store unique id, primary key
- **date**: store date (Y-m-d)
- **userId** : userId
- **isAttended** : 0 or 1

If there is more info(e.g. departments, sections) you want to store then of course you can.

**Notes: sqlite database cannot accepts boolean values so you need to store it as false = 0 or true = 1.**

Comment: Ok for todays date i take my attendance for 0 or 1. but for tomorrow ?i need whole month attendance by date. then what will i do for each and every specific date?

Comment: You can use `date()` function of sqlite to compare date part from column only with given date. [Docs here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date.asp). This will give you records for specific date. You can also query for [month](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_month.asp) and [year](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_year.asp) by applying same logic on **date** column.

Comment: How it will be saved on database? can you show me ?

Comment: Follow [this guide](https://android.jlelse.eu/room-store-your-data-c6d49b4d53a3) to store data in local database.